# Wheel won't turn?

Tags: tire, brakes, wheels

I bought a Hyper Cruiser bike last night from Walmart and as I'm pedaling home the rear wheel stops moving while pedaling.

I don't know how to fix this, please help. This is what the bike look like.

[image]

Comment: We're going to need more information. Are you able to pedal but the wheel doesn't turn? Or have the pedals locked up?

Most likely explanation for the former would be that your chain somehow slipped off. For the latter that the rear axle wasn't properly tightened, and the wheel is rubbing against the frame.

Comment: I think you mean wheel, not tire. If you bought the bike at a store take it straight back and ask for it to be fixed or replaced.

Comment: Like, I can pedal and the gears move, but the wheel doesn't turn with it. I just peddle in place.

Comment: I got it at the local Walmart, new. It was the only place close to me to get a bike so I went there. Am I better off returning it?

Comment: Walmart doesn't service bikes, and it sounds like you don't have a proper bike shop in your area, so yes, returning it would be the easiest way out of this problem.

Comment: Just to clarify - you spin the pedals, and you can see the chain moving, which drives the rear cog BUT the rear wheel doesn't catch and turn?  That sounds like a faulty freewheel/freehub.   That's the bit that makes click-click-click noises when you are coasting.   On an old bike they can be gummed up with grease and dirt, or the pawls can snap, but on a new bike it should be good for thousands of kilometres.   And while not expensive, its a cost you shouldn't have to face on a brand new bike.

Comment: Yep, take it back.

Comment: There is one thing you can try before you take it back.  Pick up the bike about a foot off the ground and drop it, onto it's tires.  If something is stuck this has a good chance of jarring it loose.

Comment: Note that this is a plain old coaster brake style bike.  Not much to go wrong with it.  Likely the problem is an assembly error on the part of the store.

Answer (score 5):

You just bought a new bike from a retail shop and it breaks down that day on the way home.  This feels like an early indication that the bicycle is rubbish and this is the start of a long list of problems that will put you off riding.

I'd absolutely suggest you return it to the shop for a full refund, immediately.

Then look for a better bike - don't discount a used bike as an option.

Comment: If you still want to fix it, please edit some clear photos of your bike's transmission area into your question.

Comment: Agreed, return it, if you want the same bike exchange it for another.